# openpyxl time format not consistent

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, time-format

I tried to set the time formatting of a cell from openpyxl. The desired format string in Excel is `'TT.MM.JJJJ hh:mm'`. Setting this in openpyxl via `ws['A1'].number_format = 'TT.MM.JJJJ hh:mm'` results in an error message while opening the workbook. Reading the manually formatted cell in openpyxl gives `'m/d/yy h:mm'`. If I set this to a new cell the result is displayed in Excel again with `'TT.MM.JJJJ hh:mm'`.

So `'TT.MM.JJJJ hh:mm'` is definitely different from `'m/d/yy h:mm'`.

This is totally strange. I'm using German formatting in Excel. Can anyone explain what's wrong here?

Comment: You have to use the English (US) formatting conventions.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, just to confirm that there are some localization/i18n "magic" spoiling the game here.

In Excel I created a table with 4 cells of identical content: `07.04.2021 17:05:00` and the following `number_format` (set within Excel). Then I opened the file using `pd.ExcelFile` (read-only, defaults to using openpyxl) and checked the number format. Result:

| Excel | Openpyxl |
| --- | --- |
| `TT.MM.JJJJ hh:mm` | `m/d/yy h:mm` |
| `TT.MM.JJJJ` | `mm-dd-yy` |
| `MMM JJ` | `mmm-yy` |
| `[h]:mm:ss` | `[h]:mm:ss` |

When changing row 3 to `MMMM JJJJ`, openpyxl reports `mmmm\\ yyyy`. So it appears that "default styles" that are typical for the source locale (i.e. TT.MM.JJJ in DE) are "smartly" adapted by Excel's defaults (m/d/yy) in an global/English context. Only custom styles that fall out of the ordinary are preserved verbatim.

Testing this, I changed the first format string in Excel to `TTTT, TT.MM.JJJJ` and got `dddd\\,\\ dd/mm/yyyy` in Openpyxl.

Digging deeper into the `XLSX` file Excel produced (just rename to ZIP and extract). File `styles.xml` for my last version of the file is illustrative:

```
<numFmts count="2">
  <numFmt numFmtId="167" formatCode="mmmm\ yyyy"/>
  <numFmt numFmtId="168" formatCode="dddd\,\ dd/mm/yyyy"/>
</numFmts>
```

So despite there being four "manually" set number formats, only the two inventive format strings make it into the file. The other formats seem to be referenced only by ID, and thus can change in representation based on application locale. And more apparently, Excel does the locale translation completely by itself. The translation of `TTTT, TT.MM.JJJJ` to `ddddd\, dd/mm/yyyy` makes it seem that it has "smart paths" for commont patterns, i.e. swapping day and month for common formats, and less smart paths for uncommon/custom format strings.

Comment: Ok, so it's a feature and not a bug.